# F# Observable - Converting an event stream to a list

Tags: f#, functional-programming, reactive-programming, observable

I was writing an unit test that verified the events fired from a class. I followed the standard "IEvent<_>, Publish, Trigger inside an FSharp type" pattern.

Can you recommend the "functional" way to achieve that?

Here are the options I can think of:

1. Convert the event stream into a list of strings and compare that list with an expected list
2. (not sure if there is a way) Convert the expected list into an event stream and compare the two streams.

Pointer to a code snipped will greatly help.

Thanks!

---

Edit 1: Answering Mark's question:

This is what I have as of now:

```
let expectedFiles = [ "c:\a\1"
                      "c:\a\2" ]

[<Fact>]
let ``Can find files from a folder`` () =
    let ad = new FileSearchAdapter()
    let foundFiles = ref []
    ad.FileFound 
    |> Observable.scan (fun acc e -> e::acc) [] 
    |> Observable.add (fun acc -> foundFiles := acc)
    ad.FindFiles @"c:\a"
    Assert.Equal<string list>(expectedFiles, !foundFiles)
```

The issues here I feel are the [a] use of reference cell [b] the observable.add is essentially overwriting the reference for each event.

Is there a functional way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Events are all about side-effects**, so it's limited how much sense it makes to try to be all *Functional* about it.

(Yes: you can build Reactive systems where immutable event data flows through a system, being filtered and aggregated along the way, but at the source, that an event is raised, is a side-effect.)

Given that a unit test tests a unit in isolation from its dependencies, testing that events are correctly raised, exercises the isolated, 'un-functional' part of a system, so I don't think you *have* to do it in a Functional way.

Here's a simpler alternative:

```
open System.Collections.Generic

let ``Can find files from a folder`` () =
    let ad = new FileSearchAdapter()
    let foundFiles = List<string>()
    ad.FileFound.Add(fun (sender, args) -> foundFiles.Add args)

    ad.FindFiles "c:\a"

    let expectedFiles = [ "c:\a\1"; "c:\a\2" ]
    expectedFiles = (foundFiles |> Seq.toList)
```

(This test function is just a normal function that returns `bool`, but I'm sure you know how to convert it to a unit test.)

Comment: List<string> does simplify the test a bit. I'll go with it. Thanks Mark!